# File descriptor valid, but call to read() returns -1

Tags: c, linux, io, serial-port, arm

My project uses serial ports on an ARM dev board.

The older version of the board (TS-7800) continues to work. I must upgrade to the newer version of the board (TS-7800-V2) to complete the project.

On the new board, I can open a file descriptor for the serial port, but when I read from the port, a -1 is returned. Here is the open file code:

```
gps_fd = initPort("/dev/ttts4", "COM3", O_RDWR, B19200);
```

That is a function call in main.c. Here is

***`initPort()`***

```
int initPort( char *port, char *name, int oflags, speed_t baudRate ){
    int fd;                     //File descriptor
    fd = open(port, oflags);    //Open the port like a file
    printf("fd = %d\n", fd);    //Print file descriptor to terminal
    assert(fd > 0);             //Open returns -1 on error

    struct termios options;             //Initialize a termios struct
    tcgetattr(fd, &options);            //Populate with current attributes
    cfsetospeed (&options, baudRate);   //Set baud rate out
    cfsetispeed (&options, baudRate);   //Set baud rate in (same as baud rate out)
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;           //Clear bit-length flag so it can be set
        //8N1 Serial Mode
        options.c_cflag |=  CS8;        //Set bit-length:   8
        options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;  //Set parity:      none
        options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;  //Set stop bit:        1
        options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    //Set flow control: none

    options.c_iflag &= ~ICANON;         //Enable canonical input
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);   //Enable receiver, and set local mode
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);      //Set new attributes to hardware
    return fd;
}
```

The `fd (gps_fd)` returns a "3", which is a good `fd`. Another application I was working in returned "15" for the `fd`, which is also good. Performing a read of the serial port:

```
bytesRead = read(gps_fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
```

Causes "bytesRead" to be -1. Putting in a "perror" line printed "Input/output error".

I am running the same code that I was running on the earlier version of the board and the device names (/dev) have not changed. Is there anything else I should look for that would cause the port not to read?

Comment: `assert(fd > 0);             //Open returns -1 on error` Then why not `assert(fd != -1)`?

Comment: Use `errno` to determine exactly why `read()` returned `-1`. The only requirement for `read()` to succeed ain't the file descriptor to be valid. Using `errno` and `read()`'s manual will help you find out what's the problem.

Comment: You're not checking return values of *any* function calls you make.

Comment: Maybe this occur for permission

Comment: Run program with super user privilege

Comment: i wonder if you could run fstat on the fd. If so, check the flags, there might be some hints there. also, does tcsetattr returns normally? Could attributes which you set cause an issue? Does it work, if you avoid setting attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everybody who commented, for increasing my knowledge!
It turns out that the FPGA (supplies hardware UARTs to the board) was turned off. This is a new board that is still in development and this is a problem the designers are aware of and they have a fix in the works. If you find yourself in a similar situation, keep in contact with the maker of the board.
This single board computer (TS-7800-V2) from Technologic Systems is great and they provide excellent customer service.